# Why does $2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 7^{m}$ always seem to contain the digit $5$ if $m>55$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I noticed that for a wide range of $m > 55$, the result of

$$ 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^m$$

always contains a $5$.

Is there a known reason for this? Or is there a counter-example?

*Note $\mathit 1$:* I only tested this for $m \leq 50,000$

*Note $\mathit 2$:* There seems to be a similar pattern for $2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 11^{m}$ (starting at $m=43$) and $2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 13^{m}$ (starting at $m=34$)

*Note $\mathit 3$:* Similar for $7^{m}$ (for $m > 25$; tested for $25 < m < 75,000$)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us how far you computed to "notice" this. When $m$ is very large your number will have very many digits. If they are more or less random the probability of avoiding $5$ shrinks to $0$ but will never be $0$. What about the other digits? What if you replace $7$ by $11$?

Comment: Tested to $200,000$.

Comment: Because there are lots of digits, maybe?

Comment: Numbers in these sequences that grow exponentially fast will probably contain every digit (in every base) after some point just because they have many digits. You need to be a little careful - powers of $10$ will just have a $1$ and $0$'s.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. But can we predict when this will happen? (I did the computation for a few other numbers and, indeed, it seems to be quite common, except that the starting point varies).

Comment: I strongly doubt that you can predict the starting point. If you tabulate the starting points for lots of digits for lots of bases you may discover statistical regularities. You can also look for the starting points for all the two digit pairs, and so on.

Comment: One cannot guarantee that, starting with some power, all digits will show up in the result: $1419213312^{25}$ has 229 digits and no digit 7 :)

Comment: @Razvan A proof of your conjecture is almost surely out of reach, but as mentioned is a counterexample very unlikely.

Comment: Covering sets are hard...

Comment: m= 1 mod 4 need not be checked they all end in 52

Comment: [This](http://www.prometheus-inc.com/asi/analysis2000/papers/montgomery_problems.pdf) may be related. See the second problem: *From this it would follow that $2^{n}$ has a 7 in its base 10 expansion, for all large n .*